# Custom comparator for achieving sort with multiple sort keys

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, compare

There is an array of integers and there is a number M.
The array needs to be sorted array with respect to the following criterion:

```
(arr[i] % M, arr[i] / M)
```

That is, the ordering is determined based on the result of `arr[i] % M`, and, in case of a tie, based on the result of `arr[i] / M`.

I know that a custom comparator can be passed like this:

```
std::sort(arr, arr + n, comp) // comp is a custom comparator.
```

But the answer would probably not be correct if I apply `sort` simply twice.

Is there any way with which we can use the `std::sort()` to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I think you need two separate `sort` calls

Comment: How,will it not result in a wrong answer?

Comment: show input and expected output.Is it like you want the values to be sorted by `arr[i]%m`, and if two values are equal then you want to sort by `arr[i]/M` ?

Comment: eg:array=4,3,2,1,M=2
after first pass:array:4,2,3,1
after second pass(the final answer):array:2,4,1,3

Comment: `std::sort` is not stable, you could get `2,4,1,3` after first pass.You might be interested in `std::stable_sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want the values to be sorted by `arr[i]%m`, and if two values are equal then you want to sort by `arr[i]/m`.

```
bool cmp(int a,int b)
{
    if(a%m < b%m)
        return true;
    if(a%m > b%m)
        return false;
    return a/m < b/m;
}
```

See [here](https://ideone.com/4PtDi4) for a working example.

Comment: Or simply `return ((a%m < b%m) || (a/m < b/m));`

Comment: @CinCout That will not work.If `a%m > b%m` we want to return `false` and not check (`a/m < b/m)`

Comment: Then `return ((a%m < b%m) || ((a%m == b%m) && (a/m < b/m)));`

Comment: That assumes global `m`.

Comment: @CinCout Now you've just refactored the function into a single, less readable IMO expression.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It is a matter of preference, my version is easily readable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
auto proj = [&](int e) { return std::make_tuple(e % M, e / M) };
std::sort(std::begin(arr),
          std::begin(arr) + n,
          [&](int lhs, int rhs) { return proj(lhs) < proj(rhs); });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but, can you please explain what is proj?its' not an object,neither a function.

Comment: `proj` is a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).

Answer (score -1):

Pair `arr[i]%M` and `arr[i]/M` now calling `sort(arr,arr+n)` in ascending order with respect to `arr[i]%M` and if `arr[i]%M` are equal with `arr[i]/M`. If you want a different sorting write a function and call sort like `sort(arr,arr+n,func)`.
Also see this.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

```
vector<pair<int,int> > v;
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    v.push_back(a[i]%m,a[i]);
}
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Here sorting by `a[i]` is equivalent to sorting by `a[i]/n` and you can get second elements by `v[i].second`.